# Java plugin refuses to run

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, java, browser-plugin

My girlfriend asked me for help with her computer; Windows 7 64-bit. She is not able to view or use anything that requires a Java plugin. I figured it would be a fairly simply fix, however, I was proven wrong on that matter. Here is what I know and any help would be appreciated.

- Tried multiple browsers to no avail. IE/Firefox/Chrome all didn’t work.
- Tried uninstalling via control panel, deleting any files on C: with Java association didn't work
- Tried typing chrome://plugins into chrome browser and enabling it didn’t work.
- Tried navigating to Java control panel to play/fix the settings didn’t work.

I am getting the unresponsive pages error and nothing will load. I even went directly to the Java website tried a clean install, verifying my version, removing old version and they all failed. I know it's not much technical information to work from but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your chrome://plugins page list Java as one of the plugins?

Comment: @JakeGould: Yes I think I mean just Java. Honestly, I'm not certain of the difference and if you know how I may confirm this, I would gladly do so for you. Thanks for the post edit by the way, I will follow suit in the future!

Comment: @MuhammadUsman: Yes the plugin page lists Java as a plugin. I will be trying David's suggestion the next time I see her and will post my findings. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman See my comment to Dave below.

Answer (score 0):

#### Java plugin refuses to run

Please try [JavaRa](https://singularlabs.com/software/javara/) to make sure you have completely removed all traces of the JRE. You can then use it to install a fresh copy of the JRE.

> JavaRa is an effective way to deploy, update and remove the Java
>   Runtime Environment (JRE). It can assist in repairing or removing Java
>   when other methods fail.
>
> [image]
>
> Its most significant feature is the
>   JRE Removal tool; which forcibly deletes files, directories and
>   registry keys associated with the JRE.

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with JavaRa in any way, I am just an end user of the software.

Comment: Dave, thanks for the suggestion. I think this may be the issue as well. However, when I tried to run the java removal tool it always failed. I will give this a go when I see her next and post my findings. Thank you!

Comment: Dave,

I tried this tool still to no avail. I just don't understand this issue. I removed Java. After doing this, I then went to the "Verify Java" page on Java's site. It prompted me with the yellow bar along the top to install the plugin (which is an improvement). However, when I reinstall and try to get this to work, I never see a yellow bar prompt to allow Java to run. I believe this is where the issue is however, I do not know how to fix the issue. Have you ever dealt with this type of issue?